# Can we allow unsecure websocket(ws://) over https protocol?

Tags: apache, https, websocket, internet-explorer-10

I have already tried using ws:// over https in firefox using some flag configuration. Is there any way to enable this configuration in IE 10 . May be by adding some reg entry it can be done but i don't know exactly which key vale to edit?

I have configured my https using apache httpd service. Which routes to my play portal URL. Is there any setting/config extra i am missing. Here is my httpd configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myhost

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/my.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/my.key


    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPreserveHost off


<Location />
SetHandler balancer-manager
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>

#ProxyPass  /excluded !

ProxyPass / http://host-to-route:9701/
ProxyPassReverse / http://host-to-route:9701/

</VirtualHost>
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sohan

Comment: Why not just use `wss://` (websocket secure) instead?

Comment: When i added wss:// urls , it prompted connection could not be eastablished. Is there something to be done on server side?

Comment: `wss://` is connect to `https` with upgrade to websocket.  Where `ws://` is connect to `http` with upgrade to websocket.  If you can connect to `https` then you should be able to use `wss://`

Comment: I am using apache server to configure my https request. Which route to my play portal url configured as ProxyPass / http://host:9701/. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with Apache httpd, but I did add the apache httpd tag to your question, now more people will see it. (might want to update your question with your apache httpd configuration)

Comment: Ok, after long R&D and coding i have made possible to use play 2.1.1 SSL and WSS. I generate cert my self and pass on and used WSS URL's. So i dropped idea to proxy pass websocket over https and decided to use https +wss. As my websockets were getting called from javascripts which is not possible to proxy pass with any proxy server.